# Getting exception error in a project I am working on: Fraction Calculator

Tags: java

Ok so i am aware that this is not done, I am in the process of working on it. Basically right now it just prints the parts of the second operand. I am getting an exception when I run the test cases I've implemented. They run, show me successful signs, however afterwards it doesn't end the program. Just throws an exception:

```
import java.util.*;

public class FracCalc {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Welcome to FracCalc! Please enter an expression and I will find the answer.");
      String expression = scan.nextLine();

      runProgram(expression);

      while (!expression.equals("quit") || expression.equals("test")) {

         Scanner scanTWO = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Please enter another expression.");
         String expressionTWO = scanTWO.nextLine();

         runProgram(expressionTWO);

      }

      System.out.println("Goodbye. Thank you for choosing FracCalc for all your calculating needs. Come back soon!");

   }

   public static String produceAnswer(String input) {

      String[] splitExpression = input.split(" ");

      //To split the expression into first operand, operation, second operation.
      String firstOperand = splitExpression[0];
      String operator = splitExpression[1];
      String secondOperand = splitExpression[2];

      return splitOperand(secondOperand);


   }

   public static String splitOperand(String operand) {

      if (operand.contains("_")) {

         String[] splitOperand = operand.split("_");

         String number = splitOperand[0];
         String fraction = splitOperand[1];


         String[] splitFraction = fraction.split("/");

         String numerator = splitFraction[0];
         String denominator = splitFraction[1];

         String operandParts = "whole:" + number + " numerator:" + numerator + " denominator:" + denominator;

         return operandParts;

      } else {

         if (operand.contains("/")) {

         String[] splitFraction = operand.split("/");

         String numerator = splitFraction[0];
         String denominator = splitFraction[1];

         String operandParts = "whole:0" + " numerator:" + numerator + " denominator:" + denominator;

         return operandParts;

         } else {

            String number = operand;

            String operandParts = "whole:" + number + " numerator:0" + " denominator:0";

            return operandParts;

         }


      }

   }

   public static void runProgram(String userInput) {

      System.out.println(userInput);

      //Run test to see if program correctly codded.
      if (userInput.equals("test")) {

         runTests();

      } if (userInput.equals("quit")) {

      } else {

         //Run user imput.
         System.out.println(produceAnswer(userInput));

      }

   }

   public static void runTests() {

      System.out.println(test("5_3/4 - 6_5/8", "whole:6 numerator:5 denominator:8"));
      System.out.println(test("-3/7 - 20", "whole:20 numerator:0 denominator:0"));
      System.out.println(test("-32 - 27/21", "whole:0 numerator:27 denominator:21"));

      System.out.println("Thank you for maintaining me and keeping me smart!");

   }

   public static String test(String input, String expectedOutput) {

      String actualOutput = produceAnswer(input);
      String testResult = "";

      if (expectedOutput.equals(actualOutput)) {

         testResult = "Success!";

      } else {

         testResult = "Failure!\nInput: " + input + "\nExpected Output: " + expectedOutput + "\nActual Output: " + actualOutput;

      }
      return testResult;
   }

}`
```

Sorry that's a little heavy, don't know where to begin looking.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the exact exception you're getting?

Comment: Also, by assigning `""` to `String testResult`, you're creating a new, empty `String` object, then by `testResult = "Success!"` you're creating one more `String` object and you have both using up memory - you're just changing what `testResult` points to. `String` class is defined as immutable in Java, which means you cannot change its text - if you try to do so, it creates a copy - see http://www.javatpoint.com/immutable-string. This might be a little thing, but those kind of things create lots of problems later on. If anything, don't initialize `testResult` with empty value.